# How to load Tradingview widget in react native ios Application locally with custom datafeed?

Tags: ios, react-native, tradingview-api

I want to use trading view widget to my React native ios application without hosting my chart to third-party CDN or other place and then use it in webview. I want it to have them within the application. I followed [this example](https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-examples/tree/master/react-native) for iOS, where they provided a basic example to do it locally. Still, unfortunately, I am not able to locate more documentation on how to use it with my custom data feed and dynamic symbols/ other properties of the chart that I can use dynamically through URL Query string if I host it somewhere. Can I achieve it locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this for Android side in react-native, but I am guessing the procedure would be the same for iOS. Inside the files provided to you by TradingView, you will find the **index.html file** in the main directory. Here is the main place where you can modify the original code and call your desired apis.

You can change configuration data, you can change the css, and you create a script tag to insert any kind of JS you desire.
You can get a very detailed documentation in here: [TradingView Documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/connecting_data/Datafeed-API).